# (Assembly newbie) Unable to access 32-bit registers in x86-64 from GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

So I am just trying to access `eax` with gdb in this easy program.

C code:

```
int main(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 3;
    int c = a + b;
    return 1;
 }
```

Here are my gdb attempts:

```
(gdb) disas 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x000000000040049c <+0>: push   %rbp
0x000000000040049d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004004a0 <+4>: movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x00000000004004a7 <+11>:    movl   $0x3,-0x8(%rbp)
0x00000000004004ae <+18>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
0x00000000004004b1 <+21>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
=>  0x00000000004004b4 <+24>:    add    %edx,%eax
0x00000000004004b6 <+26>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
0x00000000004004b9 <+29>:    pop    %rbp
0x00000000004004ba <+30>:    retq 
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) x $rbp
0x7fffffffe620: 0x00000000
(gdb) x $rbp-4
0x7fffffffe61c: 0x00000001
(gdb) x $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe618: 0x00000003
(gdb) x $eax
0x3:    Cannot access memory at address 0x3
```

So you can see, I have no trouble using `x $rbp` to access `rbp`, but I'm unable to access `eax`.

Is there some setting I need to turn on to access 32-bit registers from gdb on a 64-bit system?

Comment: Try `p $rbp` and `p $eax` instead... (And do "help x" and "help p" to learn the difference between these commands)

Answer (score 3):

The `x` command stands for [`examine`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html). It accepts a pointer as input and shows what's there. You're looking for the [`print`](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_chapter/gdb_9.html) command, or `p`, which prints its argument's value.

```
p $eax
```

By doing `x $rbp`, you're actually looking at what's on the stack. It appears that `rbp` contains the address `0x7fffffffe620` in your example.

The error message you get doing `x $eax` indicates that the value of `eax` is 3, and since that's not a valid pointer, it shows you an error message instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. So if x accepts a pointer as input, why is there a difference between what happens what I type 'x $eax' and 'x $rax'? I can access $rax just fine, but I can't access $eax, and I would assume they either both pointers or both not pointers.

Comment: You haven't shown `$rax`, but I would assume that the higher bits of `$rax` make it a valid pointer, while the lower bits by themselves don't point anywhere useful. By doing `x $eax`, you're discarding the upper half of the address (assuming that it's an address).

Comment: In other words, you can't assume that `eax` is a valid pointer on the basis that `rax` is, because `eax` is nothing more than the lower 32 bits of `rax`. It's half the size of a pointer. For a more obvious example, `al` is the lower 8 bits of `rax`, but you (probably) wouldn't think of it as a pointer.

Comment: Aaaah, okay. Because I'm on a 64-bit platform, memory addresses are 64-bit and require a 64-bit pointer to point to them. Thus, because rax is 64-bits it can serve as a pointer, and eax is the right 32-bits of it, it cannot. Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

chutiye... minus plus minus what is the value.. That many bit you need to add to memory....

**
0x000000000040049d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp

0x00000000004004a0 <+4>: movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)

0x00000000004004a7 <+11>:    movl   $0x3, error is here cos you cant add a string directly to the next memory instruction-0x8(%rbp)**

Comment: you are trying to multiply the value of the string in memory by 8 bits....

Comment: Looks like normal AT&T syntax un-optimized compiler output from `gcc -O0` to me.  There are no strings or additions in any of the instructions you showed.